# Augmented Reality on Android: Rendering stuff to the ground

Tags: android, libgdx, augmented-reality

As rendering engine, I want to use LibGdx. As AR Engine I think Vuforia could fit.

I want to place an object (2D or 3D) on the ground. What I am going to achieve: When walking through the streets, I want to see augmented objects lying there or some textual information. So how can I

- measure the current camera position (based on the sensor)
- get the real-world y compared to the current ground
- get the angle / current camera position and pose
- calculate all of the gathered data into something that I can use in libgdx for rendering the object correctly over the camera preview ?

I want to use GPS coordinates or Natural Markers for the virtual objects, so any kind of other markers can not be used. I have already found a sample that uses the sensors of the camera so that I can turn around me and see then augmented objects. However all of these "fly", I want to place them on the floor and walk on by them instead of "taking them with me".

Comment: You forgot to ask a question. ;)

Comment: Honestly there are even 4 questions. The ones with the list bubbles in front :)

Comment: Seems a bit like Pokemon Go :)

Comment: Pokemon go is just one popular example of AR being around since 4-5 years. However they did not do stuff right, so you can e.g. not walk around virtual items or place items that other players can pick up. That's what I want to do including leaving hints on the floors.

Comment: the best example of AR in LibGDX is INGRESS.

Comment: Did you find anything interesting at the end?

Comment: No, I will wait for Google Tango to evolve. In the meantime I changed my game to run on Daydream (so just VR)